# Why can a user see all databases

Tags: mongodb

We have been using 4.2.0 for a long time and everythin seems to be configured properly.  I have a user **mtpuser** that is authenticated by its own database **mtp**.  Our IT guys created a new virtual machine and installed a fresh version of MongoDB 4.2.12.

Our admin import several databases into the new 4.2.12 MongoDB from 4.2.0.  I did not watch how the IT guys installed 4.2.12 nor how our DBAdmin import the databases, but now my **mtpuser** can see and access all the databases.

Looking at **mtpuser** I see:

[image]

Any suggestions that I can look at?

Comment: If your question is about MongoDB permissions, install MongoDB locally, create a user with the permissions in question, and determine the behavior. If your question is about your installation, contact your sysadmins.

Answer (score 0):

The IT group did not add the following section to the /etc/mongod.conf

```
security:
   authorization: enabled
```